# Trouble with background audio agent and audio streamer windows phone C#

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone

So, I have this application, where I want to select a track from a list of tracks and play it. The problem is, some tracks require a media stream source for playback (for instance, an ogg file).

In the Background Audio Agent, I am instructed to leave the source property of the Audio Track to null, if i so desire to have a MSS do the decoding for me and not use the built-in chip for that.Basically, what i do in the foreground app is this:

Create an audio track instance, with its source set to null. I set the tag to carry everything needed for identifying the file so I may use that in the background agents.

In the Background Audio Agent, I follow the execution, and everything seems fine, up to the point I try to decompress the tag to figure out what the foreground app wanted to play. At this point, I get an Argument Out of Range exception, saying the Source property can not be null.

I suppose I am doing something horribly wrong, somewhere, but I don't see why would the CLR throw an exception about the source, when I want to play with the tag property.

After some more research, I figured that tracks which do not require a media stream source are handled correctly. However, if I set the source property to null, somehow, all the data from the Audio Track gets erased. My Track factory(method that creates these tracks), returns a track with no tag if I set the source to null, but works fine otherwise.

```
AudioTrack GetTrack(LowMemorySongDisplay t)
    {
        AudioTrack track;
        for (int i = 0; i < SystemSupportedFormats.Length; i++)
        {
            if (t.SkydriveSong.Name.ToLower().Contains(SystemSupportedFormats[i]))
            {
                track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("MUSIC/" + t.SkydriveSong.Name, UriKind.Relative), t.SkydriveSong.Name, t.SkydriveSong.Artist, t.SkydriveSong.Album, null, t.SkydriveSong.Compress() + "?", EnabledPlayerControls.All);
                return track;
            }
        }
       return track = new AudioTrack(null, t.SkydriveSong.Name, t.SkydriveSong.Artist, t.SkydriveSong.Album, null, t.SkydriveSong.Compress() + "?", EnabledPlayerControls.All);
    }
```

As you can see, this method returns 2 different tracks, depending on file supported format condition. An mp3 file will get a source as URI, whereas an OGG will get a null (as instructed in audio agent). This is basically the only difference in their construction.

However, the track with null source seems to ignore everything else and have all its other members null as well...

This is the method that calls it

```
void SongsList_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (App.IsmediaLib)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Play(((LowMemorySongDisplay)(SongsList.SelectedItem)).associatedSong);
            }
            else
            {
                AudioTrack track;
                var t= ((LowMemorySongDisplay)(SongsList.SelectedItem));




                //BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("MUSIC/" + t.SkydriveSong.Name, UriKind.Relative), t.SkydriveSong.Name, t.SkydriveSong.Artist, t.SkydriveSong.Album, null, t.SkydriveSong.Compress()+"?", EnabledPlayerControls.All);
                                  Collection.Clear();
                Collection.Add(new LowMemorySongDisplay(t.SkydriveSong));
                //PlayListCOntainer.ItemsSource = Collection;
                command = "fromtag";
                SaveState();
                ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).IconUri = new Uri("Assets/transport.pause.png", UriKind.Relative);
                ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).Text = "pause";
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = GetTrack(t);
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception te) { te.ToString(); }

    }
```

Exception is thrown here

```
protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
    {
        try
        {

            if (PlaylistName == null && track.Tag != null && track.Tag.Contains('>') == false)
            {
                PlaylistName = track.Tag;
                DeserializeSongData();
            }
            else if (PlaylistName == null && track.Tag == null)
            {
                PlaylistName = "allsongs";
                DeserializeSongData();
            }
            else if (PlaylistName != track.Tag && track.Tag != null && track.Tag.Contains('>') == false)
            {
                PlaylistName = track.Tag;
                DeserializeSongData();
            }

            else if(track.Tag.Contains('?') && Command=="fromtag")
            {   **//above line throws exception**
                string[] t = track.Tag.Split('?');
                NowPlaying.Add(new MusicDataStorage(t[0].Split('>')));
                Command = "donothing";
                if (NowPlaying.Count > 1)
                {
                    NowPlaying.RemoveAt(0);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.ToString(); }
            switch (playState)
            {
                case PlayState.TrackEnded:
                    player.Track = GetPreviousTrack();
                    break;
                case PlayState.TrackReady:
                    player.Play();
                    break;
                case PlayState.Shutdown:
                    SaveState();
                    break;
                case PlayState.Unknown:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Stopped:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Paused:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Playing:
                    break;
                case PlayState.BufferingStarted:
                    break;
                case PlayState.BufferingStopped:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Rewinding:
                    break;
                case PlayState.FastForwarding:
                    break;
            }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Comment: Which line, what exception? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask